# Dynamic Time slots on FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to set up an online event booking system with full calendar. I use events/Calendars tied to users, with each user having custom slotMinutes, minTime, maxTime. these values are pulled from a DB and inserted into a hidden form.

for testing I fix the values in the form in php.

```
<div id="practitioner-details hidden">
    <form action="" id="practitioner-details"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="name" value="Dr Demo"/>  
        <input type="hidden" name="timeslot" value="15"/>  
        <input type="hidden" name="starthour" value="09"/>  
        <input type="hidden" name="endhour" value="17"/>  
    </form>
</div>
```

I use jquery to read the values from the input fields on document ready as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timeslot = $('input[name=timeslot]').val().toString();
    var starttime = $('input[name=starthour]').val().toString();
    var endtime = $('input[name=endhour]').val().toString();
// Activate Current Calendar Link
$('.links #' + $('#practitioner').val()).addClass('active');

var defaultViewCal = 'agendaWeek';

// Set Event Source URL
$('#fullCalendar').attr('events', "/calendar/view/" + $('.links a.active').attr('id'));


// Initiate Full Calendar   
$('#fullCalendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        //view names are: month, agendaWeek, agendaDay
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultView: defaultViewCal,
    firstDay: 1,
    columnFormat: {
    month: 'dddd',
    week: 'dddd \n dd/MM',
    day: 'dddd dd MMM yyyy' },
    titleFormat: {
        month: 'MMMM yyyy',                            
        week: "dd MMM[ yyyy]{ '&#8212;'[ dd] MMM yyyy}",
        day: 'dddd dd MMM yyyy'  },
    //time slot - from practitioner
    slotMinutes: timeslot,
    allDaySlot: false,
    editable: true,
    selectable: true,
    //starting time (hour) - from practitioner
    minTime: starttime,
    //closing time (hour) - from practitioner
    maxTime: endtime,
    //fetch time from practitioner details
    lazyFetching: true,
    // Set Height to Prevent Scroll Bars in day and week view
    viewDisplay: function (view) {
        var h;
        if (view.name == "month") {
            h = NaN;
        }
        else {
            h = 2100;  
        }

        $('#fullCalendar').fullCalendar('option', 'contentHeight', h);
    }
});
});
```

whether I use .val().toString() or plain .val(), I know by alerting the vars that it is reading them correctly, but the calendar will not render more than 1 hour regardless of what I put in. It seems to correctly set the starting hour, but nothing else. If I hard code the times, it works as planned.

I am at a loss as to why it dies if I attempt to read the values from the form.

EDIT

some code removed from $(document).ready for calarity. In particular the event handling code.

Answer (score 1):

**Just an update:** 
in latest version V2 'slotMinutes' is changed to 'slotDuration' and value to slotDuration can be set as '00:15:00' for 15 minutes and so.

*default value is : '00:30:00' (30 minutes)*

***Regards,
Pravin B***

Answer (score 0):

the Jquery portion had to be updated as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var timeslot = $('input[name=timeslot]').val().toString();
var starttime = $('input[name=starthour]').val().toString();
var endtime = $('input[name=endhour]').val().toString();
// Activate Current Calendar Link
$('.links #' + $('#practitioner').val()).addClass('active');

var defaultViewCal = 'agendaWeek';

// Set Event Source URL
$('#fullCalendar').attr('events', "/calendar/view/" + $('.links a.active').attr('id'));


// Initiate Full Calendar   
$('#fullCalendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        //view names are: month, agendaWeek, agendaDay
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultView: defaultViewCal,
    firstDay: 1,
    columnFormat: {
    month: 'dddd',
    week: 'dddd \n dd/MM',
    day: 'dddd dd MMM yyyy' },
    titleFormat: {
        month: 'MMMM yyyy',                            
        week: "dd MMM[ yyyy]{ '&#8212;'[ dd] MMM yyyy}",
        day: 'dddd dd MMM yyyy'  },
    //time slot - from practitioner
    slotMinutes: parseInt(timeslot),
    allDaySlot: false,
    editable: true,
    selectable: true,
    //starting time (hour) - from practitioner
    minTime: parseInt(starttime),
    //closing time (hour) - from practitioner
    maxTime: parseInt(endtime),
    //fetch time from practitioner details
    lazyFetching: true,
    // Set Height to Prevent Scroll Bars in day and week view
    viewDisplay: function (view) {
        var h;
        if (view.name == "month") {
            h = NaN;
        }
        else {
            h = 2100;  
        }

        $('#fullCalendar').fullCalendar('option', 'contentHeight', h);
    }
});
});
```